# Blazor WASP App (ASP.NET Core Hosted) Trying to get a setting value from my appsettings.json file

Tags: blazor, webassembly, appsettings, configurationmanager

I am having troubles trying to get a setting from my appsettings.json file.
I put a setting for a local path named: FileStorage. Here are my files:

My appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "FileStorage": "D:\\Temp\\Storage"
}
```

My razor page:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
<h3>Configuration</h3>
<h4>File Storage: @Configuration["FileStorage"]</h4>
```

My Program.cs file (server project):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(
"appsettings.json", optional: true, 
reloadOnChange: true);
```

I have been trying many ways and still get a NULL value for FileStorage setting.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can read FileStorage setting like this       Configuration.GetValue(typeof(string), "FileStorage")

Answer (score 2):

First a quick note - Blazor WebAssembly runs in the browser sandbox and does not use the local FileSystem (you can through JavaScript and the browser's FileSystem Apis, but that is another story), so your use of `GetCurrentDirectory` and any plans you have for the `FileStorage` setting need to take that into account.

Now, you don't need to write any code to load `appsettings.json` in Blazor WebAssembly - it is loaded by default, so remove this code:

```cs
builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, 
  reloadOnChange: true);
```

Your value should be populated by default.

If you want to check the configuration is loaded, this code will list all keys/values:

```html
<article>
    <h2>Configuration</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Configuration.AsEnumerable())
        {
            <li>@item.Key: @item.Value</li>
        }
    </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: I knew that appsettings.json is loaded by default but someone told me to do this just as another option.
I already removed those lines.
I copied and pasted your article section and tested, still get NULL values.
This is a .NET 6.0 app and is a Core Hosted, so I have a CLIENT and a SERVER projects.
Im saying this because I have another solution but is a  Blazor Server App (just one project) and I did the same and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Did you place your appsettings file in the Client wwwroot folder?

Comment: You guys are awesome. 
I placed the appsettings in the wwwroot folder and now is working.
So, this means any user can read the all content of the file?
I'm concern about ConnectionString, maybe I need to do a custom settings file then. Sorry, maybe that was a silly question, Im new in Blazor dev.

Comment: You should not be using connection strings in Blazor WebAssembly - it runs in the Browser and will hopefully (if your security is good) not be able to connect to a database. Database connection strings belong on the server - where you create a web api for the WebAssembly client to call.